# How to get data.next() and data.complete() here in the following code?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

How can I get the data.next() and data.complete() in the following code. isn't data here acts as observer?

when I am trying to call those method I am getting an error

component.ts file

```
 this.authservice.registerform(form).subscribe(data => {
     data. ?
     this.ifsuccess = true;
     this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['']);
     }, 1200);});
```

Service.ts

```
 registerform(data): Observable<any>{
return this.httpclient.post('http://localhost:3000/login',data);
```

}

I am a beginner to Angular and rxjs. Please help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> isn't data here acts as observer?

No, in your example `data` is the emitted ("next") value.

When you subscribe to an observable, you can pass three different parameters, which are handlers for `next`, `error`, and `complete`.

example:

```
someObservable$.subscribe(
    next => console.log(`next value is: ${next}`),
    err  => console.log(`error is: ${err}`),
    ()   => console.log('someObservable$ completed!) 
);
```

In your case, you are only providing the first handler to the `subscribe()`, method.  You can access the next value simply by using the param name `data`:

```
this.authservice.registerform(form).subscribe(
    data => {
        // 'data' refers to the emitted value
        this.ifsuccess = true;
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['']);
        }, 1200);
    }
);
```

If you need to handle completion or error, simply provide the other handlers as well:

```
this.authservice.registerform(form).subscribe(
    data => {
        // 'data' refers to the emitted value
        this.ifsuccess = true;
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['']);
        }, 1200);
    },
    error => console.log('error occurred!'),
    ()    => console.log('registerform call completed')
);
```

It is also possible to pass a full observer object to the `subscribe()` method, instead of individual handler methods:

```
const myObserver = {
    next:    val => console.log(`next val: ${next}`),
    error: error => console.log(`error: ${error}`),
    complete: () => console.log('complete!')
};

someObserver$.subscribe(myObserver);
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66320753?file=src/app/app.component.ts) with a sample.